# python web framework for ERP development

Tags: python

I want to start developing an ERP for small companies, So I'd like to know what python web framework is highly recommendable for?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any particularly suited for ERPs. Check out a list of all the current frameworks: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks.

Answer (score 2):

[openerp](http://www.openerp.com/) is open source and written in python, it uses cherrypy and other things

Answer (score 2):

A open source erp solution called ERP Next [ https://erpnext.com/ ] uses python framework called WNF Framework [ https://github.com/webnotes/wnframework ]  .You can ask for a free demo and gauge the

Answer (score 2):

[Frappe](https://frappe.io) is the underlying framework of ERPNext, you can check it out. Documentation is relatively unavailable though so you may have to work your way through the source.

Comment: Now it has good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out web.py. It's a very minimalist Python framework and gives you the flexibility you might need to build something outside of the mainstream data-driven app

http://webpy.org/